# Search in Array of Dictionaries by key name

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, search

I have an array of dictionary, in which i need to search and return matching Dict

```
let foo = [
    ["selectedSegment":0, "severity":3, "dataDictKey": "critical"],
    ["selectedSegment":1, "severity":2, "dataDictKey": "major"],
    ["selectedSegment":2, "severity":1, "dataDictKey": "minor"],
]
```

In `foo`, how can i find for `severity:2` and get matching Dict ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `filter` function

```
let foo = [
  ["selectedSegment":0, "severity":3, "dataDictKey": "critical"],
  ["selectedSegment":1, "severity":2, "dataDictKey": "major"],
  ["selectedSegment":2, "severity":1, "dataDictKey": "minor"],
]

let filteredArray = foo.filter{$0["severity"]! == 2}
print(filteredArray.first ?? "Item not found")
```

or `indexOf`

```
if let filteredArrayIndex = foo.indexOf({$0["severity"]! == 2}) {
  print(foo[filteredArrayIndex])
} else {
  print("Item not found")
}
```

or `NSPredicate`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "severity == 2")
let filteredArray = (foo as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
print(filteredArray.first ?? "Item not found")
```

**Swift 3 Update:**

- `indexOf(` has been renamed to `index(where:`
- `filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)` has been renamed to `filtered(using: predicate)`

Comment: Very good, but I'd make two tweaks: 1) Remove the `!` from the filter expression, and instead of `if ! filteredArray.isEmpty { ... }`, just do a `print(filteredArray.first ? filteredArray.first! : "Not found")`.

Comment: Thanks @vadian. Is `filter` faster than `map` ?

Comment: @NRitH Thanks, I considered your suggestion using the nil coalescing operator.

Comment: `filter` and `map` are two different things. `map` can transform the items of the array to another type for example

Comment: @vadian, if you use the nil-coalescing operator, won't your `print()` output `Optional<>` if `filteredArray.first` is non-`nil`?

Comment: @NRitH No, if `filteredArray.first` is not `nil` the value will be unwrapped. That's the benefit of this operator.

Comment: @vadian : I have an array like this: `let menuDict = ["id" : model?.itemID , "quantity" : Int(tappedMenuCell.lblQuantity.text!)] as! [String : Int]`.
Now when I am writing this: `let foundItems = menuDict.filter { $0["id"] == model?.itemID }` , it shows me the error: `Type '(key: String, value: Int)' has no subscript members` .

Comment: @iPeter Your *array* is a **dictionary**. `filter`ing a dictionary treats the dictionary as array of tuples.

Comment: How do I achieve my goal sir! Please help me to clarify `filtering`. This is where I get stuck every single time.

Comment: Filtering a one-dimensional dictionary is not very useful. You can check directly if the key with the desired value exist.

Comment: @vadian : I got my point where I was wrong. Now I am filtering an array of type `[[String : Int]]()`. Now when I am writing `let foundItems = self.arrOrderData.filter{$0["id"] == model?.itemID}` , I am getting the error as `Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type '_OptionalNilComparisonType'`.

Comment: I don't know of what static types your objects are but either you have to unwrap all optionals or make the affected `Int?` type conform to `OptionalNilComparisonType` as suggested in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
if let index = foo.flatMap({ $0["severity"] }).indexOf(2) {
    print(foo[index])
}
```

Another way of doing it.

The first example only works if the user is 100% sure all the dictionaries contains `"severity"` as a key. To make it more safe:

```
if let index = foo.indexOf({ ($0["severity"] ?? 0) == 2 }) {
    print(foo[index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you work on swift 3.1 -**

```
 let  resultPredicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "<your Key> CONTAINS [cd] %@", <value which you want to search>)
 let filteredArray = requstData.arrayForColl?.filter { resultPredicate.evaluate(with: $0) };
```